# Tabelau geographical heatmap and overlaying data from two different datasets

Tags: google-maps, google-fusion-tables, tableau-api

Now I'm trying to overlay latitude and longitudinal points from two different data sets, resulting in two different markers for each one on a geographical map. There is no relationship between the two data sets. Tableau doesn't seem to be able to accomplish this directly. I don't want to group the data at all, just plot the lat and lon points. Any suggestions?

I would also like one of the datasets above to be a heatmap, i.e. each data point plotted has its intensity correlated to the dimension. Besides the overlaying problem above, accomplishing a geographical heat map alone is not working for me. My geographical heat map by latitude and longitudinal points is not conveying the information I want. The lighter color marks are on top of the darker color marks. However, I want the darker color marks to be in front. How do I achieve this?

Would Google Maps or Fusion Tables be a better option for me?

Comment: As you are using two sets of data fusion table could be a good idea but again it is hard to suggest something with surety without knowing exact purpose and expected result. This documentation should help: https://support.google.com/fusiontables/answer/2571232?hl=en.

Comment: Also, about the markers you can keep lower zIndex for the ones you want in the back. Good practice is to input objects in gradual z order - which means inputting things you want in the back, first.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by combining the two datasets into one using `UNION ALL`, making sure to add an extra column with a descriptor designating the originating source (i.e., which of the two datasets). I then set up a calculated field to determine what data to visualize and how to visualize it.

As regards to the heatmap, the solution was to bin the data and then sort it when plotting. Without binning, sorting appears not possible using Tableau.

I took a look at Google Maps and Fusion Tables, but the functionality and visual aesthetics are currently not at the Tableau level.